# Python: Write the data into multiple columns of output file

Tags: csv, python-3.5, read-write

I am writing a python solution to read the first column of a file called Input.txt (tsv) and write to a file called Output.txt (tsv).

```
    import csv

    with open('Input.txt', 'r') as rf:
        reader = csv.reader(rf, delimiter='\t')

        with open('Output.txt', 'w') as wf:
            writer = csv.writer(wf, delimiter='\t')

            desired_column = [0]

            for line in reader:
                Column1 = list(line[i] for i in desired_column)
                writer.writerow(Column1)
```

The above code reads the first column of Input.txt and writes into the first column of Output.txt.

**My Question is:** What should i do if i would like to write the same data also into the second column of Output.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('Input.txt', 'r') as rf:
    reader = csv.reader(rf, delimiter='\t')

    with open('Output.txt', 'w') as wf:
        writer = csv.writer(wf, delimiter='\t')

        desired_column = [0]
        for line in reader:
            Column1 = list(line[i] for i in desired_column)
            '''We can use writerows function to zip the value. Instead of
               different column name , we can use same copied column to satisfy your requirement'''   
            writer.writerows(zip(Column1 ,Column1 ))
```

Hope this satisfies your requirement .See this https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows